# Cast 32-bit value to HANDLE

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, casting

I am dealing with a component that provides a 32-bit custom handle, and I'd like to wrap that using the standard windows HANDLE type. In a legacy component, I've seen use of the following two conversion methods:

```
// value is 32-bits
auto value = GetCustomHandle();

HANDLE hA = HANDLE(value);
HANDLE hB = (void*)(SIZE_T)value;
```

Are hA and hB always equivalent? If not, under what circumstances are they not?

In this instance, I think they are always equivalent because:

1. There's no difference between functional and c-like casts.
2. HANDLE is equivalent to void*.
3. The size of void* and SIZE_T is 32-bits on 32-bit systems, and 64-bits on 64-bit systems.

Thanks.

Comment: `SIZE_T` seems to be a non-standard macro; you should make sure that its size is the same as `void*`'s perhaps with a static assert `static_assert(sizeof(void*) == sizeof(SIZE_T), "Oops!")`. Based on the data you've given, the conversions should be value-preserving.

Comment: The definition of `SIZE_T` is defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SIZE_T

Comment: What does GetCustomHandle return?

Comment: Note that handles are 64 bits on x64.

Comment: Cup: GetCustomHandle always return a 32-bit value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go with the C++ style cast:

```
 HANDLE hCPP = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(value);
```

You may get a warning for "casting narrow type to wider type" (or whatever the terminology the compiler uses for that), in which case the expression should be:

```
 HANDLE hCPP = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(value));
```

The type `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be unsigned and match the size of a pointer. Using MS-defined types will just make it less portable - not generally a big problem in Windows software, but it's certainly no benefit to make code LESS portable.

Comment: To clarify, can you let me know if you agree that the two conversion methods above are equivalent? As for your point of using a C++ style cast, I can understand that. I am just trying to understand if the legacy code are equivalent. On a related note, what would be the reasoning behind a warning for "casting a narrow type to a wider type"? Can't be due truncation...

Comment: `HANDLE(value)` is largely equivalent to the first form, and your second variant is equivalent to the my second variant. It's the opposite of truncation, and 64-bit compilers often warn when you try to convert a 32-bit value to a 64-bit pointer - since that would, if the 32-bit value has previously been a pointer, mean that the value has been truncated (the compiler really warns because you may have not considered that pointers are wider than your integer type, and thus can't have the full range).